# p:commandButton ajax not called inside p:dataList

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Primefaces 2.2.1

Mojarra 2.1.2

I have a sophisticated method in my jsf bean :

```
public void saySomething() {
   log.debug("SAY SOMETHING !");
}
```

And a simple button in the jsf :

```
<p:commandButton
   value="say something"
   process="@this" update="@none" action="#{timetableBean.saySomething}" />
```

Clicking on the button, results in my simple logging :

```
DEBUG PhaseTracker - BEFORE PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
DEBUG TimetableBean - SAY SOMETHING !
DEBUG PhaseTracker - AFTER PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
```

Let's go to next simple case.
When placing that identical button inside a p:dataList like this :

```
<p:dataList id="groupUsers2" value="#{timetableBean.group.users}" var="user" itemType="circle" style="padding:0; margin: 0;">
   <p:commandButton
      value="#{user.data['selected'] ? 'V' : 'X'}"
      process="@this" update="@none" action="#{timetableBean.saySomething}" />
   <p:commandLink value="#{user.userId} - #{user.name}" process="@this" />
</p:dataList>
```

Clicking on the button, results in my simple logging :

```
DEBUG PhaseTracker - BEFORE PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
DEBUG PhaseTracker - AFTER PHASE INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
```

The method of saySomething() was not called !

What did i do wrong ?

Comment: The problem might be the `process` attribute.  What is this really saying because a commandButton component will be created for each element of `#{timetableBean.group.users}`.  What does `@this` supposed to actually process?

Comment: @maple_shaft: i changed it into process="@form", and it's still not working, the listener method is not invoked ..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Problem solved.

Found the solution in [here](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5843)

In order for listener to be invoked, the components inside the p:dataList should be encapsulated with `p:column`

```
<p:dataList id="groupUsers2" value="#{timetableBean.group.users}" var="user" itemType="circle" style="padding:0; margin: 0;">
  <p:column>
   <p:commandButton
      value="#{user.data['selected'] ? 'V' : 'X'}"
      process="@this" update="@none" action="#{timetableBean.saySomething}" />
   <p:commandLink value="#{user.userId} - #{user.name}" process="@this" />
  </p:column>
</p:dataList>
```

Strange though, i didnt see this in the documentation, as it doesnt specify the p:column. Perhaps it's in the errata for primefaces 2.2.1 doc ?

Related problems [here](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7355).

Comment: Yes I don't see it in the 2.2.1 documentation either.  Sorry I wasn't more of a help.

Comment: @Cagatay Civici: Hi Optimus. In my 2.2 doc, p.118 is talking about ajax pagination, and i still dont see it saying about p:column. Perhaps it's implicit ?

Comment: @maple_shaft: Thank you. Appreciate the effort !