# Command Link with in a datatable not working

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am having a problem with primefaces command link.
I have two `<h:form>` which are not nested the link from the second `<h:form>` is not triggered.

```
<h:form>
 <p:dataTable>
  <p:column>

  </p:column>
  <p:column>
   <p:commandLink onclick="dialog.show()"/>
  </p:column>
 </dataTable>
</h:form>

<p:dialogBox widgetWar="dialog">
 <h:form>
  <p:dataList value="#{bean.List}" var="var">
   <p:commandLink value="#{var.name}" actionListener="#{bean.viewName(var.id)}"/>
  </dataList>
 </h:form>
</p:dialogBox>
```

The command Link from the dialog box is not working and there are no exceptions thrown.
Can any one help?

Comment: What do you mean by `not triggered`? Did you check if the execution enters the method `viewName`? Also what that method is supprot to work. Please provide code that is ready to be copied, pasted and executed. See this http://sscce.org/

Comment: tried using ajax="false" ?

Comment: @yannicuLar I tried using ajax="false" even then its not triggered. But If I am avoiding datatable and if I am simply calling a method it works. Could not figure out what actually the problem is.

Comment: @miroslav_mijajlovic By **not triggered** I meant that the call is not reaching the method mentioned in **actionListener**. I tried using debug mode and the call never reaches the method.

Answer (score 1):

Your command Link shoud be inside `<p:column>`.

```
<p:dataList value="#{bean.List}" var="var">
  <p:column>
   <p:commandLink value="#{var.name}" actionListener="#{bean.viewName(var.id)}"/>
  </p:column>
</p:dataList>
```

This is necessary in order tou have data Selection inside `dataList`. Related problem is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761958/pcommandbutton-ajax-not-called-inside-pdatalist)